# Shuffle some divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to shuffle the cells of my `div` table. I tried using the `.shuffle()` plugin, but couldn't make it work. Here's my code:

```
<div class="sprites">
    <div class="row">
        <span id="draggable0" class="draggable"></span> 
        <span id="draggable1" class="draggable"></span> 
        <span id="draggable2" class="draggable"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span id="draggable3" class="draggable"></span> 
        <span id="draggable4" class="draggable"></span> 
        <span id="draggable5" class="draggable"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span id="draggable6" class="draggable"></span> 
        <span id="draggable7" class="draggable"></span> 
        <span id="draggable8" class="draggable"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I tried to shuffle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sprites').shuffle();
});
```

Do you know how I could shuffle all this stuff?

Comment: Is the shuffle function something you created yourself? Or is it being pulled in from an alternative plugin?

Comment: What do you want to do? Shuffle the spans inside the divs or shuffle divs inside the larger div?

Comment: i'd like to shuffle randomly my spans, so they can be in any div, in any row. I'm trying to use the shuffle plugin :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/Vhh59/)

This will only shuffle elements of class `sprites`. You want to shuffle the `div`s inside `.sprites`, right?

```
$('.sprites div').shuffle();
```

EDIT: The correct syntax might actually be:

```
$.shuffle('.sprites div');
```

Comment: They might even be wanting `$('.sprites span')`, but I'm not sure if jquery would handle that correctly.

Comment: Yep, `$('.sprites span')` is probably the one - just tested... oh, and `$('.draggable')` works too

Answer (score 0):

`shuffle()` shuffles the elements passed on to it... you need to pass the items inside your box to it...

Just use this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nYh9Q/)

```
$('.draggable').shuffle();
```

or

```
$('.row').shuffle();
```

**Update**

Use this to re-enable dragging.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.draggable').draggable(); 
});

function shuffle () {
    $('.draggable').draggable("destroy");
    $('.draggable').shuffle();
    $('.draggable').draggable();
}
```

*The shuffle code*

```
(function(d){
    d.fn.shuffle=function(c){
        c=[];
        return this.each(function()
            {
                c.push(d(this).clone(true))
            }).each(function(a,b)
            {
                d(b).replaceWith(c[a=Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)]);
                c.splice(a,1)
            })
    };
    d.shuffle=function(a){
        return d(a).shuffle()
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you! I got it to work, when my page loads, my span are correctly shuffled, but i can't drag them anymore :/

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'd guess that's because `shuffle()` is using `replaceWith()` to facilitate the reordering, which means you'll need to reinitiate the `Draggable`.